# Opening an Android App from another Android App using Intents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, manifest

I am having an issue opening one of my other application using Intents in Android.
Here is what I have right now:

```
        val packageName = "com.myapp.demo.application"
        val activityName = "$packageName.WelcomeActivity"

        try {
            val intent = Intent().apply {
                setClassName(packageName, activityName)
                action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
            requireActivity().finish()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "App not installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
```

And the manifest in the second application looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp.demo.application">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <activity android:name=".SimpleScannerActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions and features declarations go here -->
    <!-- ... -->

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />

</manifest>
```

I am always getting this exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp.demo.application/com.myapp.demo.application.WelcomeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

What I am missing here?
I have tried starting another application with different package name and it worked with the same code, but not for my `com.myapp.demo.application`. Maybe something is not right with my demo application manifest?

Comment: you can't open activity from other app directly. So explicit Intent will not work. You need to open it through url as Implicit Intent. You need to read about handling urls in your app (deep link) Example: `Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  

intent.setData(Uri.parse(“your handled url in first app”)); 

startActivity(intent); `

Comment: It works with the same exact code for my other application - I am directly opening explicit intent, I cannot understand why it is not working for my given example on the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to launch the start(activity with the catergory LAUNCHER ) activity of your appA from appB, then it can be done using :

```
val launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.demo");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
```

And if you want to open some other activity then create a deep link uri for that activity.

**Add the data tag in manifest.xml of appA**

```
 <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "demo://myapp” -->
        <data android:scheme="demo"
              android:host="myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
```

**Adding the queries tag in the manifest of appB**

```
  <queries>
        <package android:name="com.myapp.demo"/>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

**Launching the activity of appA from appB**

```
          val uri = Uri.parse("demo://myapp")
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)


            intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, actually I made it work using the first method (at least the first half ) - here are a few remarks - My application uses flavors and the only way it worked is by using `"com.myapp.ewmapp.application.standard"` (where .standard is extention)  and then passing it like this `packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)`
Unfortunately when I try to pass data as  `intent.putExtra("dataKey", "test")` - I get null from the other application. Can you help me with that please?
Also the second method did not worked for me.. I am not sure what I am missing...

Comment: Playing around with the scheme and host worked for me finally. I was able to open specific intent and passing an array of data with it.