# How to remove my Android App from share menu list

Tags: android, google-maps, filtering, intentfilter

I would like to know how can I remove my app from share menu list of other apps except for Google Maps.
I added to my Manifest an Activity with an intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

This configuration causes my app to be present in all the share menu lists of other apps.
Is there any way to be present only in Google Maps share menu list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**remove line**

```
 <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

**Edit**

The line above will not show your application in all other applications

**Take a look here**

[Opening an Android App from another Android App using Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680021/9381727)

Comment: If I remove it my app cannot be shown into share menu for all apps

Comment: I modified the answer

Comment: I don't want to open my App "A" from my App "B", I would like that my App "A" is listed only into share menu of google maps App and not in other Apps share menu like YouTube Amigo etc etc ...